# Image uploader won't accept URL the first time

Tags: bug, status-completed, images, uploader, userscript

I've found a bug with the Stack Exchange image uploader, that occurs when attempting to use a custom URL to link to an image.

Let's take this [lovely image as an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ulQ7H.png); if I try to use the custom URL the first time, I get this error:

[image]

However, if I *close* the image custom URL error message & try again with the custom URL, it works fine:

[image]

[Related chat messages from when I first noticed the bug.](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/26100877#26100877)

I have found this bug exists on both Meta & the main Stack Overflow site.
I am using Chrome 45.0.2454.101 m, on Windows 8.1 Professional.

Comment: Does this happen _all the time_ or just intermittently? Are you using any userscripts or extensions that may interfere with things? It works for me first time, consistently. (I'm using Chrome 45.0.2454.101 too, albeit on OS X.)

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young It happens 100% of the time. Yes, I'm using a userscript (the SOCVR `cv-pls` userscript) & Adblock Plus. I'll do some testing and get back to you.

Comment: Confirmed, it's a problem with the [StackImgurByLink](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Siguza/StackScripts/master/StackImgurByLink.user.js) Tampermonkey userscript. Reporting the bug to the developer now.

Comment: Fixed.​​​​​​​​​

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(This was caused by a userscript of mine, which I developed in response to [this MSO question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/306888).)

[Fixed](https://github.com/Siguza/StackScripts/commit/2b0cacfd8b220ef2344db56815600d072ee4263e).

I changed it to simply call `.click()` on the link instead of hiding the div and making the other one visible, because that's what humans do too, so it has to work.
I'm not sure what was causing the bug (and I didn't care to investigate, since I found a fix), but I assume there are some event handlers listening on that link, which my script previously bypassed.

Comment: Yep, all the clickable elements in the image uploader change a whole bunch of state, so it's indeed important to trigger the `click` event for them. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Turns out that it's a bug caused by the [StackImgurByLink](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Siguza/StackScripts/master/StackImgurByLink.user.js) Tampermonkey plugin- I forgot that I had it installed!

[Reported the bug to Siguza](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/26105246#26105246) and hopefully will be fixed.